# Can TableForm accept a list as a cell?

Tags: output-formatting

I have a plot and a list (containing elements of different types) and need to display them in `TableForm` in one column, a plot above a list. `TableForm` builds a table, first column of which includes a plot and first element of a list.

```
TableForm[{Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]], {"Some", "text", "and", ToExpression["\\frac{for}{mulae}", TeXForm]}}]
```

If a list includes only strings, `StringJoin` solves the problem, but this is not my case. How to place entire list into one cell of `TableForm`?

Comment: Try using [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html).

Comment: Indeed, it seems, `Row` with separator works fine